# How can I start the python SimpleHTTPServer on port 80?

Tags: permissions, python, webserver

I am using this command on Ubuntu but it is starting on port 8080 and I don't have another server running so I'd like it to start on port 80. I saw ways that you could set up a bash script to do something like this, but isn't there a command line flag or something simpler to specify the port?

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Comment: Are you running as root? You can't listen on a port <1024 unless you have root privileges - and I would strongly advise against that.

Answer (score 227, accepted):

`sudo python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80`

for **python 3.x** version, you may need :

`sudo python -m http.server 80`

Ports below 1024 require root privileges.

As George added in a comment, running this command as root is not a good idea - **it opens up all kinds of security vulnerabilities.**

However, it answers the question.

Comment: I might also add that running this command as root is **not** a good idea - it opens up all kinds of security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Very nice, and good to know. But why is it that ports less than 1024 require root? Because they are used for common things like FTP and SSH? BTW - I was using this temporarily to test firewall rules - worked very well.

Comment: @cwd :) The TCP/IP port numbers below 1024 are special in that normal users are not allowed to run servers on them. This is a security feaure, in that if you connect to a service on one of these ports you can be fairly sure that you have the real thing, and not a fake which some hacker has put up for you.

Comment: @cwd If you want to run the server on a port <1024, use iptables to route incoming connections to a port ≥1024. For testing, do something like `sudo nc -l 80` ([netcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat)). And see [Why are the first 1024 ports restricted to the root user only?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/16564)

Comment: @jrg A port <1024 only matters if you trust the sysadmin on the server but not other users. It's near-userless outside a few local networks nowadays: most servers aren't multiuser machines.

Comment: This is a related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2699907/183066) about how to drop privileges once you've opened port 80.

Comment: Yay. I was just looking for how to use a custom port with SimpleHTTPServer from the command line.

Comment: is it possible to call this in a py2x and py3x compatible way? I tried using the six library but it doesnt seem to work with:
'python -m six.moves.SimpleHTTPServer'

Comment: The command above for python 3.x should be `sudo python3 -m http.server 80`

Answer (score 6):

Do something like :

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 50505
```

Where `50505` is the port number.