# Netcat listens on a wrong port

Tags: networking, netcat

When I run the command `nc -l -p 443` it starts listening but when I try connecting to it it fails. A few hours later I tried with verbose mode `nc -lvp 443` and it printed out `listening on [any] 2443`. Then I figured out that it's not listening on the correct port. Any ideas why it's listening on port 2443 instead of port 443?

Comment: You are not doing this as root, I guess?

Comment: What implementation of `nc` are you using and what Unix are you running?

Answer (score 0):

With default setup, only `root` can bind to ports lower than 1024.

```
panki@REDACTED:~$ nc -lvp 443                                                                                         
Can't grab 0.0.0.0:443 with bind : Permission denied                                                                    
panki@REDACTED:~$ sudo !!                                                                                             
sudo nc -lvp 443                                                                                                        
listening on [any] 443 ...
```

More about this is already said here: [Why are the first 1024 ports restricted to the root user only?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16564/why-are-the-first-1024-ports-restricted-to-the-root-user-only)